# Singleton for Embeded RavenDb

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, ravendb

Why when I use this singleton the load retreive always null?

```
public class DataLayer
{
    private  EmbeddableDocumentStore d;
    private static object lockerSingleton = new object();

    private static DataLayer _current;
    public static DataLayer RavenDB
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockerSingleton)
            {
                if (_current == null)
                    _current = new DataLayer();
            }
            return _current;
        }
    }

    public DataLayer()
    {          

                d = new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { DataDirectory = "csv" };
                d.Initialize();              
    }

    public void  store<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var session = d.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(obj);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public T retrieve<T>(object ID)
    {
        using (var session = d.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Load<T>(ID.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us an example of `ID` please.

Comment: By conventions Raven encode IDs like so: `posts/1` if `T: Post`. So just passing 1 won't work.. unless `T` has a `int` property `Id`?

Comment: Does your code work without the Singleton pattern? The locking seems a little odd to me. Usually a static instance of IDocumentStore is enough, optionally managed by DI.

Comment: Can you provide a complete sample?

Comment: I can provide my code tomorow without thé singleton it works. Lock is more for the initialize.

Comment: Lock is because i working in à possible multithreaded web application Too

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement the repository pattern.  Don't.  http://novuscraft.com/blog/ravendb-and-the-repository-pattern

Comment: @Matt very good Remark i will try it, but it doesnt tell me it doest work

Comment: @maxbeaudoin not true - Doing .Load<Post>(1) is the same as .Load<Post>("posts/1"), RavenDB will make a call to GetDocumentId

Comment: @Phill good to know I suppose I tried passing the string 1 like Matt Johnson pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your object has an integer Id field.  So let's say you have an object of Foo with its Id set to 1.  Raven will store your document with the document id of "foos/1".

When you are calling Load, if you pass in the integer 1, Raven will properly translate that back to the "foos/1" string.  But because you are passing in the string "1", raven just assumes that the string represents the entire document id.  In your case, it does not.  A document does not exist with the document id of "1", so you get a null.

Also, generic T is redundant on store, you might as well just use object.

But please, heed my comment about not using the Repository pattern with Raven.  It hides the vast majority of Raven's functionality, and will get you into trouble when you start querying.

Comment: THX I'll Try it tomorow, in the blog he advise to initialize session for each http request, so for Ms mvc 3 For each action right? Do you know if it's more advise to put the initialize code in the begin request of global.asax?

Comment: If you do, make sure you dispose it when the request ends.  The raven guidance says to base-class your controllers: http://ravendb.net/kb/3/using-ravendb-in-an-asp-net-mvc-website  You could also inject it with a DI framework that implements a lifetime of per-web-request.  There are other options too.  All that really matters is that each request gets their own session instance but they all share the same document store.

Comment: it was as you said the ToString() that cause the problem, thank you